# Creating a list using csv.reader()

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to create a list in python from a csv file.  The CSV file contains only one column, with about 300 rows of data.  The list should (ideally) contain a string of the data in each row.

When I execute the below code, I end up with a list of lists (each element is a list, not a string).  Is the CSV file I'm using formatted incorrectly, or is there something else I'm missing?

```
filelist = []                
with open(r'D:\blah\blahblah.csv', 'r') as expenses:
    reader = csv.reader(expenses)
    for row in reader:
        filelist.append(row)
```

Comment: Show your input and output.

Comment: A CSV is a sequence of rows. A row is a sequence of column values. The column values are strings. So, iterating a CSV like this _should_ give you a list of lists of strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`row` is a row with one field. You need to get the first item in that row:

```
filelist.append(row[0])
```

Or more concisely:

```
filelist = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(expenses)]
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work.  It didn't occur to me to stress the specific item within the row, when there is only one item to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your "csv" doesn't contain any seperator like ";" or ",".
Because you said it only contains 1 column. So it ain't a real csv and there shouldn't be a seperator.

so you could simply read the file line-wise:

```
filelist = []
for line in open(r'D:\blah\blahblah.csv', 'r').readlines():
    filelist.append(line.strip())
```

Comment: Not a good idea because of escaped separators and quotes and other csv typical signs...

Comment: Yes COULD be. Depends on the input file and if it is a rfc-compliant csv or just plain text file.

Answer (score 0):

Each row is read as list of cells.
So what you want to do is

```
output = [ row[0] for row in reader ]
```

since you only have the first cell filled out in each row.

Comment: So slow when typing on my cellphone -.-*